# Using tooltipster Dynamically Jquery

Tags: jquery, tooltip, dynamic-html, tooltipster

I use tooltipster plugin for my tooltip

```
$(function(){
     $('.tooltip').tooltip();
});
```

Now the `.tooltip` that were added later dynamically does not respond to `tooltip()`

Now many will say to call `$('.tooltip').tooltip();` each time i add those elments. But since i have hundreds of thousands of elements that contain `.tooltip` and are created from `hundrends` of `functions` I cannot call the `$('.tooltip').tooltip();` hundred times . Is there any alternative ?

Comment: See the discussion [over here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25119796/tooltipster-does-not-work-in-a-generated-content/25122249#25122249

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such cases, delegate listeners are a good option. You listen for mouseenter events (for example) on a common ancestor and create and show the tooltip on the hovered child accordingly. Tooltipster has API methods that allow this.